# npm startのエラーについて

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

Reactの環境構築をしたいのですがフォルダを作って

```
npx create-react-app tutorial
cd turotial
npm start
```

としてみたのですが npm start後、localhost3000を表示する途中で「このサイトにアクセスできません」と出てしまいます。

npmのバージョンは6.9.0,nodeのバージョンはv12.0.0です。

以下エラーメッセージです。解決策を教えていただければ幸いです。

```
Fatal error in , line 0
Check failed: U_SUCCESS(status).
FailureMessage Object: 00000066E18FD9C0npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225477
npm ERR! tutorial@0.1.0 start: react-scripts start
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225477
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tutorial@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

---

マルチポスト先:

- [JavaScript - npm start のエラーについて｜teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/187321)

Comment: 質問者さんは teratail でも[同一内容の質問を投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/187321)されていませんか？StackOverflow でコメントするのも変ですが、 teratail は[**マルチポストを推奨していません**](https://teratail.com/help#posted-otherservice)。マルチポストを行うのであれば、 teratail の質問文内にて、その旨を記述するべきだと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 にて質問文と同じ環境を作成し、 `npm start` を実行したところ、同様のエラーが発生しました。

```sh
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: U_SUCCESS(status).
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 000000000028DBA0npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225477
npm ERR! tutorial@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225477
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tutorial@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tusr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-01T16_21_48_061Z-debug.log
```

そこで、 **tutorial ディレクトリを削除**し、 **Node.js のバージョンを 12.1.0 にアップグレード**した後、 `npx create-react-app` からの**手順を再度行う**ことで、該当エラーが改善されました。

Comment: 試してみますありがとうございます！　マルチポストについては早く解決したいと焦って全く知らずに投稿してしまいました。ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Comment: refs: [#27379](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27379), [#27415](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/27415)